# org-capture link description too long

Tags: org-mode, org-capture

I configured org-capture with below elisp in init.el:

```
(define-key global-map "\C-cc" 'org-capture)
(setq my-org-capture-file (concat org-directory "/capture.org"))
(setq my/line "%(with-current-buffer (org-capture-get :original-file-nondirectory) (thing-at-point 'line t))")
(setq org-capture-templates
      `(
        ("n" "Review Notes"
         entry (file+headline ,my-org-capture-file "Code Review")
         ,(format "* TODO %%?\n %%l\n  %s" my/line))
      ))
```

Then when I review code to take notes with 'n', I got below results:

```
** TODO 
 [[file:/tmp/linux-4.14-rc8/drivers/video/fbdev/geode/video_cs5530.c::static%20int%20cs5530_blank_display(struct%20fb_info%20*info,%20int%20blank_mode)]]
  static int cs5530_blank_display(struct fb_info *info, int blank_mode)
```

It works perfect but the link description is too long. I wish to display the file name without path and line info, e.g. video_cs5530.c for this case.

I try to use %a to replace %l, results is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe making it a link with an annotation of the current file name would work:

```
(setq org-capture-templates
  `(
    ("n" "Review Notes"
     entry (file+headline ,my-org-capture-file "Code Review")
     ,(format "* TODO %%?\n [[%%l][%%f]]\n  %s" my/line))
  ))
```

Comment: That's awesome! I am thinking about use elisp replace things before but sounds like not so easy!